# Click e segurar o Button / Listview

Tags: android, listview, click

Como programo para ao click e manter pressionado chame um método diferente de somente um click normal?

Gostaria de dicas, tutorias algo que possa me ajudar.

Estou tendo um novo problema preciso utilizar o método OnItemClick e o método onItemLongClick ja implementei o onItemClick e estou em duvida como implementar tambem o

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(), inalcancaveis_tela.class);
        startActivity(intent);}
```

chamo esse metodo no onCreateView

`list.setOnItemClickListener(this);`

OBS: to utilizando extends Fragment

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Se você utilizou a interface `View.OnClickListener` para definir uma ação para o botão (usando o método `setOnClickListener`), você pode utilizar o `OnLongClickListener` também.

[`View.OnLongClickListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnLongClickListener%28android.view.View.OnLongClickListener%29) poderá te ajudar a implementar esse listener.

```
View view = ...;

view.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        //....
    }
});
```

É importante retornar `true` se você tratou o evento, retornando `false` irá permitir que o evento de `Click` seja chamado.

Comment: @Walkin você sem querer respondeu uma dúvida minha (não cheguei a perguntar aqui no site) que deixei como pendência do meu projeto. Eu trato um evento de click e um de click longo, só que quando eu usava o click longo o evento de click também era chamado. Não sabia que era por causa do retorno false ou true. Muito obrigado. +1 para sua resposta.

Comment: É... Esses parâmetros de retorno de eventos são bem complicados, já tive vários problemas com isso. Fico contente que tenha ajudado.

Answer (score 3):

```
Button myButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
        System.out.println("Clique simples");
     }
     });

myButton.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
     @Override
     public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        System.out.println("Clique longo");
        return false;
     }
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

Todas as subclasses de `View` (`TextView`s, `ImageView`s, etc.) possuem um método `setOnLongClickListener()` que recebe como parâmetro uma implementação de `View.OnLongClickListener`. Agora é só procurar por exemplos no Google.

No caso particular de listas de itens (`ListView`s), caso você queira aplicar o long click a um item da lista, deverá chamar `setOnItemClickListener()`, que recebe uma implementação de `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`.

Comment: Mas , e para eu colocar o evento de compartilhamento nesse botão com longclicklistener?

Comment: Cara, faz um tempo que não mexo mais com Android então não tenho como lhe ajudar. Mas lance uma nova pergunta no stack que com certeza será respondida.