# Botão que ao clicar e segurar ele tenha uma função de compartilhamento

Tags: android

Tenho vários botões que ao clicar , emite um som , quero fazer com que ao clicar e segurar o botão apareça as opções de compartilhamento , para facebook whatsapp etc 
como faço isso ?, segue código do meu botão

```
            ImageButton sehloiro = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.sehloiro);
            sehloiro.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, 
            R.raw.sehloiromp3);
            mp.start();

        }
    });
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html

Comment: relacionada http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14761/click-e-segurar-o-button-listview

Comment: Deu certo valeu! Ack

Comment: @Paiva abs brow! Precisar, tmj.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para colocar um evento ao segurar no botão, basta você usar o `OnLongClickListener` como citou o @Luc no comentário. Veja como pode ser feito

```
sehloiro.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
        showDialogShared(); // esse é o método para chamar o dialogo
        return true;
   }
);
```

Logo, você pode criar um `AlertDialog` para mostrar a opção de compartilhamento:

```
public void showDialogShared() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builderSingle = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this,
            android.R.layout.select_dialog_item);
    arrayAdapter.add("Compartilhar");

    builderSingle.setAdapter(
            arrayAdapter,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    String strName = arrayAdapter.getItem(which);
                    if (strName.equals("Compartilhar")) {
                        // aqui você coloca o código de compartilhamento
                    }
                }
            });
    builderSingle.show();
}
```